# Отличние map от each

Tags: javascript

В чем заключается отличие метода `map` от `each`?

Comment: в яваскрипте **нет** функции `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличие функции [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) от функции [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) заключается в том, что первая - возвращает **новый** массив, в то время как вторая - просто применяет callback к каждому элементу массива.